# Space above header only in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

How to remove extra space above nav bar in `Home tab`? I tried to style inline but it craps the other nav menus and fixs `home` . [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Gcf.png) 
HTML

```
        <header id="masthead" class="site-header clearfix">
            <div id="header-text-nav-container" class="clearfix">
                <div class="top-bar">
                    <div class="inner-wrap clearfix">

                        <div id="header-left-section">
                                <div id="header-logo-image">
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name', 'display')); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_theme_mod('colormag_logo')); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name', 'display')); ?>"></a>
                                </div><!-- #header-logo-image -->
                        </div><!-- #header-left-section -->
```

CSS

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
html {
    overflow-y: scroll; /* Keeps page centred in all browsers regardless of content height */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* Prevents iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling user zoom */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/controlling_text_size_in_safari_for_ios_without_disabling_user_zoom/ */
}
----------------------------------------------- */
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
* html .clearfix {
    height:1%;
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
/* =BODY
----------------------------------------------- */
body {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-size: cover;
}
#page {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.wide {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.wide #page {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.inner-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 970px;
}
#header-text-nav-container {
        background-color: #fff;
}*/
#header-text-nav-wrap {
    /*padding: 20px 0 25px;*/
    background-color: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#header-left-section {
    float: left;
}
#header-logo-image {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 160px;
}
#header-logo-image img {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    max-height: 58px;
}
#header-text {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
#site-title {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 1.3;
}
#site-title a {
    color: #da3532;
    font-size: 46px;
}
#site-description {
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #666666;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    /*  font-family: 'SimHei', '黑体', 'STHeiti', '华文黑体', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;*/
}
```

Comment: Hello, please provide at least a sample of the code and a link or an image showing us the problem...

Comment: Are you logged into the WP admin in one browser?

Comment: Yes I am logged in, but the space appears in incognito mode as well

Comment: Add actual code that can be run, not images of code.

Comment: I edited the question to show the code as text @Turnip. Shamima, could you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and try to stick to the recommendations, because, as it is now, your question is not answerable...

Comment: Hi Gaspacchio, I will read them, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess and say this is the cause:

```
    body {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

You are using padding on the body element. Because the body is a main wrapper using padding on it will confine all elements within it leaving gaps around your site.

Set both padding's to `0px`

Comment: You should probably sort that image out as well.. god chance it could be affecting it